# Call to undefined function anchor() in

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi everyone I am  new to a `PHP` framework `codeIgniter`, I am going over the user guide iv ran in to a problem, I am on the part where you load helper file but for some reason my code just in not working I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function anchor() in /home/fresherd/public_html/CI/system/application/views/blogview.php on line 17
```

now im not 100% sure that it is loading the helper file this could be causing the but I am not sure how to detect the file has been loaded

any advice will help many thanks, Alan

Answer (score 5):

If you are not sure please check the autoload.php file in the config folder or in your controller put the following function:

```
<?php
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add url in helper inside autoload.php inside config folder.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or you can add this inside your function

```
 $this->load->helper('url');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just load the helper in your controller or put it in the auto load array.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

I would also change Gerardo's code to this:

`function _construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}`

Comment: thanks mate but for some reason it just isn't working

this is my code what I have

blog.php file :

<?php
class Blog extends Controller
{
 function _construct() 
 { 
  parent::__construct(); 
 }
 
 function index()
 {
  $data['todo_list'] = array('Clean House','call mum','do other jobs');
  
  $data['title'] = "My array title!";
  $data['heading'] = "My array heading";
  
  $this->load->view('blogview', $data,",true");
  
  $this->load->helper('url');
 }
 function comments()
 {
  echo 'Look at this!';
 }
}
?>

Comment: blogview.php file

<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
 
 <h3>My todo list </h3>
 
<ul>
 <?php foreach($todo_list as $item):?>
 
 <li><?php echo $item;?></li>
 
 <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
 <?php echo anchor('blog/comments','Click Here');?>
</body>
</html>

know in me its something really easy like a spelling error..

Answer (score 2):

loading the helper in the controller solved my problem,, jus try this way

```
<?php
    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    }
?>
```

or try putting it in autoload array in config.php in the application/config folder., like

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

hope it helps...

Comment: I moved on from PHP 3 years ago but hopefully comments will still help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your controlLer, has the parent statment in the construct

```
function __construct(){
     parent:: ControlLer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload your helper so you dont have to reload it on every page..

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or manually load it on every page..

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```